# How to save a file to a specific directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am using this code to save a downloaded file but it is placing them in the same folder where it is being run from.

```
r = requests.get(url)  
with open('file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

How would I save the downloaded file to another directory of my choice?

Comment: `open('somefolder/file_name.pdf', 'wb')`…!?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Or if in Linux, try:

```
# To save to an absolute path.
r = requests.get(url)  
with open('/path/I/want/to/save/file/to/file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)


# To save to a relative path.
r = requests.get(url)  
with open('folder1/folder2/file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

See [open() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) docs for more details.

Comment: what about if it's a downloaded zip folder and you want to save it in a directory

Comment: The above would also work to save a zip file (the path defined as as a URL) to a specific directory (e.g. `/path/I/want/to/save/file/to/archive.zip`).  Or do you mean to download an archive from a URL and extract it to a folder?

Answer (score 10):

You can just give `open` a full file path or a relative file path

```
r = requests.get(url)  
with open(r'C:\path\to\save\file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have access to the directory you can simply change your `file_name.pdf'` to `'/path_to_directory_you_want_to_save/file_name.pdf'` and that should do what you want.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a quicker solution:

```py
r = requests.get(url) 
open('/path/to/directory/file_name.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: The file is opened but not closed. This is not a good practice.