# How to donwload xlsx file from a website with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, download, python-requests, xlsx

I am trying to download a file automatically and save it. It is suppossed to be easy but I am founding some difficulties.

In theory is supposed to be easy [here](http://url%20=), you click automatically you download the file.

I have try different ways (as found in diffeent posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415405/downloading-an-excel-file-from-the-web-in-python) or [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699682/how-to-save-a-file-downloaded-from-requests-to-another-directory)). Here a couple of example of mhy current code:

Option A)

```
url = "https://www.gov.scot/binaries/content/documents/govscot/publications/statistics/2020/04/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/documents/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/govscot%3Adocument/HSCA%2B-%2BSG%2BWebsite%2B-%2BIndicator%2BTrends%2Bfor%2Bdaily%2Bdata%2Bpublication.xlsx"

response = requests.get(url,stream=False)
with open(dowload_folder_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

Option B)

```
xl_df = pd.read_excel(url,
                       sheet_name='Table 5 - Testing',
                       skiprows=range(5),
                       skipfooter=0)
```

In both cases I just get

`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>`

Any suggestion, please?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)
    with open("data.xlsx", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)


main("https://www.gov.scot/binaries/content/documents/govscot/publications/statistics/2020/04/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/documents/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/trends-in-number-of-people-in-hospital-with-confirmed-or-suspected-covid-19/govscot%3Adocument/HSCA%2B-%2BSG%2BWebsite%2B-%2BIndicator%2BTrends%2Bfor%2Bdaily%2Bdata%2Bpublication.xlsx")
```

[image]