# Read Excel file with pandas from url reponse

Tags: python, excel, urllib

I am looking how to read an xlsx file with pandas, with the file hosted on SharePoint. These contents, when shown through reponse.text, are in string but are a binary representation of the file.

> PK╚╝    ! #h�╔�╔  �═   �╔[Content_Types].xml ��╔(� ╗
> ��[O�@��M�;���1��G% {�΀��.Z�E��Ҧݝ�I{��5�╗"j� ���"╚W�J�I!^_Z�"CR�R�;(�
> P  ��g��U ̸�a!�D�FJ,�`�>�㕱�V?Ɖ
> ���    �n�}%K��������Pv���k'#�Dv��W� �B0�T�F��U? -?�*_�-K�"� � dM�fb|═"�BndF0x�3UΕ�Nu�
> ���P�lO�Y�ğ#� �����,g�K#�}�����E=�tD�U�}���O�Q�[��F�|Ix��╚���[H2{�H+╚x�k�]dn�a�╔yZ"N�jͺ�"ih�s�Gn�<j�╚

I would like to know how to read this format into memory so that I can call pd.read_excel with it.

I've tried to use urllib and openpyxl, in this manner:

```
    import openpyxl as excel
    import pandas as pd
    from io import BytesIO
    import urllib
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url=req) as reponse:
        rsp = reponse.read()
    excel.load_workbook(filename=rsp)
```

But I am getting error 400 Bad Request, from the urllib request module.

The url looks something like this:

[https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test-department/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test-department/DepartmentDocuments/test/Book1.xlsx')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true](https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test-department/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/test-department/DepartmentDocuments/test/Book1.xlsx%27)/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true)

Comment: The `filename` parameter would imply an actual file on disk, not the content of the file. Have you tried writing the response to a file?

Comment: I could write it to memory; the question is how do I get the file in the first place from the url

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699682/how-to-save-a-file-downloaded-from-requests-to-another-directory/44699728

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it. the key was to seek back before passing the file to pandas.

```
file_ext = self.file_name.split('.')[-1]
if file_ext == 'xlsx':
    import pandas as pd
    from io import BytesIO
    xl = bytes(memoryview(response.content))
    memfile =BytesIO()
    memfile.write(xl)
    memfile.seek(0)
    df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(memfile, engine='openpyxl')
    print(df.head(10))
```